# Is it possible to create a Font from a pixel-based colour image? (for Pygame, but also otherwise)

Tags: python, fonts, colors, pygame

I've been working with Pygame and have run into a problem.  I would like to use a custom font with metallic-looking characters, but I don't know how.

To be more precise, I want to create text that will look something like the image here:
[image: gold, metallic looking text]

All font types I know about are based on black-and-white (and I think vector-based) images, but to my knowledge this is to make them scalable and allow them to change colour - I don't need this sort of functionality for my purposes however.

Is there a font format or some other means to create a 'fancy', multi-colour using font like the above using a png/tif/bmp/some other pixel-based picture format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had no luck finding bitmap font formats that support colour (let alone work with python 3.4/pygame), but the other solution presented by user3191557 below put me on the right track.

I ended up creating a png image containing the string of characters I needed (all equally spaced/sized in the image) from left to right.  In my case, I just needed numbers from 0 to 9.  Here's the code I used (hopefully I didn't miss out anything relevant):

```
import pygame

WINDOWWIDTH = 1080
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1080
Window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

class CustomFont: #The letterimage file must consist of equally-sized letters, each of 'lettersize', arranged in a single line, left-to-right.  The letterstring is a string representation of the letters in the image (in the same order).
    def __init__(self, letterstring, lettersize, letterimagefile):
        self.letterstring = tuple(letterstring)
        self.lettersize = lettersize
        self.letterimagefile = letterimagefile
    def write (self, string, position):
        stringseparated = tuple(string)
        for i in range(len(stringseparated)):
            letter = stringseparated[i]
            for j in range(len(self.letterstring)):
                if self.letterstring[j] == letter: #j gives us the index number of the letter in our original string
                    grabletterbox = ((self.lettersize[0] * j), 0, self.lettersize[0], self.lettersize[1]) #this defines the position of the rectangle that will grab the letter from our letterimage file, as well as the size of said rectangle     
                    Window.blit(self.letterimagefile, ((position[0] + (i * self.lettersize[0])),position[1]) , grabletterbox)

ActiveNumbersSprite = pygame.image.load('.\images\ActiveNumbers.png') #The image used for the numbers
ActiveNumbers = CustomFont('0123456789', (36 , 60), ActiveNumbersSprite) #This tells the program what characters the ActiveNumbersSprite image contains, in what order, how big each character is (as (x,y), and the name of the image file
...
```

With that, I can just use ActiveNumbers.write(string, (x,y)) to write whatever string I want in my font (assuming I have images for the required characters, of course) at whatever x,y position I want in the window.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Most "early" font formats are based on bitmap fonts, so you will probably get lucky, there.

For a simple case, there is a "bitmapped font" snippet for pygame [here](http://www.pygame.org/pcr/bitmap_font/index.php). This does not implement (word-)wrapping and other fancy things.

However, you can also roll your own more or less easily:

- Create a large bitmap with the characters in your font as in your example.
- Create a map character -> rectangle in bitmap. In the simplest case, you only need the width of each character (even simpler when all characters are the same width)
- In your render function, take a string of characters as input and a starting position.
- Lookup each character from your string rendering the characters left-to-right, moving to the left by the width of the character just displayed.

Hope that helps

Comment: I like the idea of using one of those 'early' bitmap font format since it seems like it has low spec requirements (unlike OpenType).

However, it looks like all the Bitmap font formats I've looked at only support monochrome images.  What formats support full colour bitmaps?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know PyGame, but OpenType has a few specs that'd allow for exactly what you need. The only problem: the thing that renders the font will have to support these [new and bleeding edge specs](http://pixelambacht.nl/2014/multicolor-fonts/). In the world of browsers, for example, some of these techniques work in Firefox, some in IE11, and some only when it's installed as a system font on Mac.

But you could do [colorful game fonts like these :)](http://pixelambacht.nl/2014/compyx-a-multicolor-8bit-font/)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a lib or a "font". this is not a font, it is a set of bitmaps. You can use some sprite class, there is even a built-in in pyGame but I prsonally never used so dont know). What I would do: 
1. set up a table with widths of your every single letter bitmap. 
2. set up a surface list with bitmaps with same indexes as in table with widths
3. set up a function to draw the text lines, where the X coordinate of every next character to blit will be calculated from the corresponding width.

And with fixed width would be much simpler, but your font is not fixed-width.